# Route to subfolder in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to route to the `Edit` page in a subfolder within my `Companies` model's view (Views/Companies/Employees/Edit).

I tried to do it using `<a asp-action="Employees/Edit" asp-route-id="@model.ID">Edit</a>` in the **Index.cshtml** of the Companies model's view which opens a blank page with the link `http://localhost:xxxxx/Companies/Employees%2FEdit/1`. The correct view should be on `http://localhost:xxxxx/Companies/Employees/Edit/1`.

Can anyone explain to me why I'm getting this?

This is the Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Comment: It's a view model :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't set the `asp-controller` attribute.

```
<a asp-action="Employees/Edit" asp-route-id="@model.ID">Edit</a>
```

should be

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Employees" asp-route-id="@model.ID">Edit</a>
```

I'm not sure why you have the sub folders the way you do.
It's supposed to be `Views/ControllerName/ActionName` (that's the convention)

Do you have an `Edit` action in the `Employees` Controller? or an `Edit` action in the `Companies` controller?

Comment: Bingo. Thank you!

Comment: @VyNguyen would be nice if you could click on the 'tick' sign by the answer to accept it :)

Comment: Note: @scartag was right. I didn't need a subfolder. I just moved Employees.csthml back to the main Views folder & add "asp-controller" to the tag. It works fine now.